# How to verify that "puts" has been called with a certain message?

Tags: ruby, mocking, rspec

I'm trying to make this test fail :)

```
it "should display the question" do
  @ui.should_receive(:puts).with("What's your name?").once
  @ui.ask_question("What's your name?")
end
```

At the moment it passes even if I don't call puts in my function.

Comment: what is your code in your method ask_question ?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, @ui should call .puts on an object that probably defaults to $stdout. Then in your tests, you can replace $stdout with a StringIO object that you can set expectations on. This has the added benefit of making your @ui object more flexible.

Comment: Can you give me an example of substitution of $stdout?

Answer (score 1):

Given the code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spec'

class UI
  def ask_question(q)
  end
end

describe UI do
  before do
    @ui = UI.new
  end

  it "should display the question" do
    @ui.should_receive(:puts).with("Whats your name?").once
    @ui.ask_question("Whats your name?")
  end
end
```

I get the failure:

```
F

1) Spec::Mocks::MockExpectationError in 'UI should display the question'
#<UI:0xb738effc> expected :puts with ("Whats your name?") once, but received it 0 times /home/avdi/tmp/puts_spec.rb:15:

Finished in 0.002575 seconds

1 example, 1 failure
```

What version of RSpec are you using?

Comment: Interesting! I'm using rspec 2 beta maybe it's a problem with the new version. I'm going to try with the older rspec.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [stringio](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/index.html) or [ZenTest](http://zentest.rubyforge.org/ZenTest/ZenTest.html), the following ruby-talk [thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/120872) has more info.